# Reading a jar file from resource location

Tags: java

In my application I have to read a jar file available in the disk location and segregate .classes file from the jar.

Code is

```
     JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("./resources/CD.jar");

    for(Enumeration<JarEntry> em = jarFile.entries(); em.hasMoreElements();) {  
        String s= em.nextElement().toString();
        ZipEntry entry = jarFile.getEntry(s);

        String fileName = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/")+1, s.length());
        if(fileName.endsWith(".class")){
            System.out.println(fileName);
        }
```

But I am getting an error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\resources\CD.jar (The system cannot find the path specified).
```

Comment: What do you mean by **segregate**? Do you mean that you want to list the file names inside `.jar` file only or you want to do something else? I can see that your code only displays the name

Comment: Try adding the full path to the file.

Comment: I want to list out the .classes files inside the jar.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem:

1. Add the 'resource' location to the classpath
2. Allow external service API to place cd.jar in resources location
3. Using a child class loader add the cd.jar to the classpath
   code snippet is given below:

   ```
   URLClassLoader childLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { getURLOfTestclass() },  this.getClass().getClassLoader());

   URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("CD.jar");
   return url;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the CD.jar file in your classpath? I would try doing that once.

Comment: I don't think this would make any difference.

Comment: This jar file is not in my class path.External service placed that file in this location

Answer (score 0):

Change `".\resources\CD.jar"` to a fully qualified URI. Eg:`C:\Users\Whoever\Documents\resources\CD.jar`.

Comment: But then it wont work for general purpose, that is if I want to run my application in linux machine I have to change the code. Isn't it?

Comment: @ANP Precisely. A solution to that would be keeping `cd.jar` in the same folder as your application.